# Does UFT12.01/ALM11 not support QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest.ID?

Tags: hp-uft, alm

I use **`UFT 12.01`** and **`ALM 11`**.
I ran a line **`msgbox QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest.ID`** but UFT gave an error stating **`Object required`**.

How do i get the **`TestSetTest ID`**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**It should work.**

```
MsgBox QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest.ID
```

shows the current ID (UFT 12.01, ALM 12.01) . If I use a different test set for execution, it shows a different ID, so i guess it is the correct ID.

Maybe you are not connected, or the test is not in stored in QC/ALM?